# Navigation cannot be found from the current destination Destination

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

X, Y 2 fragments

1. X to Y Works (X->Y)
2. Cames back Y to X works (Y->X)
3. again go to Y from X (X->Y) It crashes and says (Fragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com)

Starting fragment with below code

````
findNavController().navigate(action)```

I just do ```findNavController().navigateUp()``` in Y fragment while coming back

Args are being sent and received successfully.
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: val action=XFragmentDirections.actionXFragmentToYFragment(
                                        args.email,
                                        args.userType
                                    )
                                findNavController().navigate(action)

Comment: This is code I use to navigate from X fragment to Y

Comment: @AliImran facing the same issue, did you solve it?